# json string parse error

Tags: jquery, json

I have a Json string as-

```
var RetailerData = {};

// The object that the JSON string should represent, can use this as it is if you want.

RetailerData.webSites = [
{
    id: 1,
    text: 'J.Crew',
    image: 'images/retailer-logo/jcrew.png',
    extra: 'www.jcrew.com'
},
{
    id: 2,
    text: 'GAP',
    image: 'images/retailer-logo/gap.png',
    extra: 'www.gap.com'
}];
```

I want to parse it using jquery  `$.parseJSON`  to get each value. I have tried it using

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(RetailerData.webSites);

$.each(obj, function() {
    console.log(this['id']);
});
```

But getting continuous error in each try. Can anyone tell a proper method for doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSON is a **string**. What you've got over there is already a JavaScript object. There's not much to parse here, eh?

Comment: sorry if I asked something stupid, I am still in learning phase. Can you please explain me in a simple way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to turn a JavaScript object into a JavaScript object, which just doesn't make sense! What you can do is

```
var str = JSON.stringify(RetailerData.webSites);
```

and use `str` to transfer your data somewhere else. Then use

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

to get your original object back after it's been modified (or not) from another source.

Comment: Does it make more sense to first serialize an object, then deserialze it? Just use `RetailerData.websites` right away.

Comment: Hence the "use `str` to transfer your data somewhere else". The whole purpose of stringifying the data is portability.

Comment: Considering the fact that the OP showed the unnecessary parsing step and usage of the object in one code block, it's safe to assume that there's no need to "transfer data somewhere else". Serializing would only make sense for interaction with (external) APIs which require a fixed format - such as JSON. Within a JS application, however, (de)serializing twice is just a redundant step.

Comment: I'm assuming from his sample code that he is unsure about what JSON is used for, so I'm just giving him an example that might help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You use `parseJSON` to parse a jsonString to json object.

But in your case `RetailerData.webSites` is already a json object no need to parse it.

```
var obj = RetailerData.webSites;

$.each(obj, function() {
    console.log(this['id']);
});
```

Comment: There's not such a thing called "json object" (excluding the `JSON` object containing `JSON.parse`, etc.). What you actually meant is a JavaScript object, denoted using object literals (`{}`). The N in JSON stands for *notation*; JSON is a *string format*, no more, no less.